# How to test bandwidth and latency over ssh with X11?

Tags: ssh, x11, x-server, bandwidth

I am working remotely on a machine using X11 trusted forwarding with 'ssh -Y`.
How can I test the latency and bandwidth between me and the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[x11perf](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/x11perf.1.html):

> The x11perf program runs one or more performance tests and reports how
>   fast an X server can execute the tests.
>
> Many graphics benchmarks assume that the graphics device is used to
>   display the output of a single fancy graphics application, and that
>   the user gets his work done on some other device, like a terminal.
>   Such benchmarks usually measure drawing speed for lines, polygons,
>   text, etc.
>
> Since workstations are not used as standalone graphics engines, but as
>   super-terminals, x11perf measures window management performance as
>   well as traditional graphics performace. x11perf includes benchmarks
>   for the time it takes to create and map windows (as when you start up
>   an application); to map a pre-existing set of windows onto the screen
>   (as when you deiconify an application or pop up a menu); and to
>   rearrange windows (as when you slosh windows to and fro trying to find
>   the one you want).
>
> x11perf also measures graphics performance for operations not normally
>   used in standalone graphics displays, but are nonetheless used
>   frequently by X applications. Such operations include CopyPlane (used
>   to map bitmaps into pixels), scrolling (used in text windows), and
>   various stipples and tiles (used for CAD and color half-toning,
>   respectively).
>
> ...

Comment: I think I need to be the systems administrator in order to run this, correct?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang - I don't have to be, but it is a Solaris 11 system, wich is the only running X server I have access to at this time.  Try it and find out on your system.